# Google maps API markers content hide by default

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Circles</title>
                <style>
                  html, body {
                    height: 100%;       
                    margin: 0px;
                    padding: 0px
                  }
                  #map-canvas {
                    height: 450px;
                    width:100%;
                    margin: 0px;
                    padding: 0px
                  }
                </style>
                <script>
                function initialize() {
                    var openedInfoWindow = [];
                    var locations = [
                    ['<div style="overflow:hidden;width: 250px;"><p>marker content</p><a style="background:#C785DB;color:#ffffff;padding:10px 50px;" href="http://asteriadiamonds.com/en/appointmet" alt="book an appointment with Asteria Diamonds">BOOKAN APPOINTMENT</a></div>', 22.28522,114.155454],
                    ['Marker 2', 31.112813,121.381709],       
                    ['Marker 3', 22.536733,114.117746],       
                    ['Marker 4', 39.922174,116.429486],       
                    ['Marker 5', 31.229686,121.525165],       
                    ['Marker 6', 25.204849,55.270783],       
                    ['Marker 7', 51.215363,4.420155],       
                    ['Marker 8', 48.856614,2.352222],       
                    ['Marker 9', 51.51884,-0.108119],       
                    ['Marker 10', 51.515553,-0.088366],       
                    ['Marker 11', 46.202415,6.157759],       
                    ['Marker 12', 34.075376,-84.29409],       
                    ['Marker 13', 40.765852,-111.897878],       
                    ['Marker 14', 40.756956,-73.979834],       
                    ['Marker 14', 32.084064,34.801722]       
                    ];
                    var cityCircle;
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                        zoomControl: true,
                          zoomControlOptions: {
                            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
                          }

                    });
                    var icon10175412 = { url: 'http://asteriadiamonds.com/skin/frontend/asteriadiamonds/default/images/map-marker.png', origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),};

              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: map.getCenter(),
                icon: icon10175412,
                map: map
              });

                   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                   var icon10175412 = { url: 'http://asteriadiamonds.com/skin/frontend/asteriadiamonds/default/images/map-marker.png', origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),};





                    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                            map: map,                     
                            icon: icon10175412,
                            content: locations[i][0]

                        });

                        bounds.extend(marker.position); 

                        openedInfoWindow[i] = null;

                        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i, infowindow) {

                           return function () {

                                if(openedInfoWindow[i] != null){                            
                                    openedInfoWindow[i].close(); 
                                    openedInfoWindow[i] = null;
                                }else{                   
                                   infowindow.setContent(this.content); 
                                   infowindow.open(map, this); 
                                   openedInfoWindow[i] = infowindow;
                                   google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
                                      openedInfoWindow[i] = null;                        
                                  });
                                }   
                            }               
                        })(marker, i, infowindow));         

                        google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
                    }

                    map.fitBounds(bounds);

                    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
                        map.setZoom(2);
                        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
                    });
                }
                function loadScript() {
                    var script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' + 'callback=initialize';
                    document.body.appendChild(script);
                }

                window.onload = loadScript;

                </script>
              </head>
              <body>
                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
              </body>
            </html>
```

I am struggling with hiding the content of the markers on page initiall load, so only when the marker is clicked i would like to show its content.

i am sure i am missing something very simple, will greatly appreciate your assistance on the matter.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of changes:

1)The line `google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');` trigger click event for every marker, it explains why all info windows  are getting visible once the map is loaded.

2)In your case there is no need to instantiate multiple instances of `google.maps.InfoWindow` objects, it is enough to reuse a single instance between markers (see the below example)

3)Instead of:

```
var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
    map.setZoom(2);
    google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
});
```

you could utilize `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce` event:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function () {
    map.setZoom(2);
});
```

4) You could consider to load Client-side APIs like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

instead of:

```
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' + 'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
window.onload = loadScript;
```

**Modified example**

```js
function initialize() {
    
    var locations = [
    ['<div style="overflow:hidden;width: 250px;"><p>marker content</p><a style="background:#C785DB;color:#ffffff;padding:10px 50px;" href="http://asteriadiamonds.com/en/appointmet" alt="book an appointment with Asteria Diamonds">BOOKAN APPOINTMENT</a></div>', 22.28522, 114.155454],
    ['Marker 2', 31.112813, 121.381709],
    ['Marker 3', 22.536733, 114.117746],
    ['Marker 4', 39.922174, 116.429486],
    ['Marker 5', 31.229686, 121.525165],
    ['Marker 6', 25.204849, 55.270783],
    ['Marker 7', 51.215363, 4.420155],
    ['Marker 8', 48.856614, 2.352222],
    ['Marker 9', 51.51884, -0.108119],
    ['Marker 10', 51.515553, -0.088366],
    ['Marker 11', 46.202415, 6.157759],
    ['Marker 12', 34.075376, -84.29409],
    ['Marker 13', 40.765852, -111.897878],
    ['Marker 14', 40.756956, -73.979834],
    ['Marker 14', 32.084064, 34.801722]
    ];


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }

    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var icon10175412 = { url: 'http://asteriadiamonds.com/skin/frontend/asteriadiamonds/default/images/map-marker.png', origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), };


    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            //icon: icon10175412,
            content: locations[i][0]

        });

        bounds.extend(marker.position);


        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infowindow.setContent(this.content);
             infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function () {
        map.setZoom(2);
    });
}
```

```css
 html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
}

#map-canvas {
            height: 450px;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
 <div id="map-canvas"></div>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much , I have implemented all of your suggestions, and now my code looks like that:

Comment: if you dont mind i will appreciate your five cents, on how to add numbering to all the markers from 1-15.
So each marker will have an following number on the marker image.

Comment: I'm away at the moment, get back to u when I'm back

Answer (score 1):

You are triggering the click even on every marker in your code. Remove this line:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
```